# Display conditional values in a Formtastic select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

How do I instruct Formtastic select to only display values based on a condition?

```
- semantic_form_for @member do |f|
  - f.inputs do
    = f.input :person
    = f.input :role, :include_blank => false
    = f.input :active
```

I only want the :person input to list/select people who are active i.e. person.active == true. I tried to pass a condition hash map to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a two step process.

First you need a means of selecting only People that are active. Next you need to pass that collection of active people to the formtastic input via the :collection option.

Step one selecting only active people: This is as simple as `Person.find(:all, :conditions ["active = ?",  true])`. But I think this is better accomplished with a named scope in the model.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  named_scope :active, :conditions => {:active => true}
end
```

Now `Person.active` is the same as `Person.find(:all, :conditions ["active = ?",  true])`

Step two, updating the form:

```
- semantic_form_for @member do |f|
  - f.inputs do
    = f.input :person, :collection => Person.active
    = f.input :role, :include_blank => false
    = f.input :active
```

Answer (score 0):

You can supply any custom collection of values through the :collection option:

`f.input :person, :collection => Person.find(:all, :conditions => "whatever")`